# multiple resultsets vs multiple calls for performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a fairly high performance application, and I know database connections are usually one of the more expensive operations. I have a task that runs pretty frequently, and in the course of business it has to select data from Table1 and Table2. I have two options:

1. Keep making two entity framework queries like I am right now. select from Table1 and select from Table2 in linq queries. (What I'm currently doing now).
2. Created a stored procedure that returns both resultsets in one query, using multiple resultsets.

I'd imagine the cost to SQL Server is the same: the same IO is being performed. I'm curious if anyone can speak to the performance bump that may exist in a "hot" codepath where milliseconds matter.

Comment: Now that I wrote all that out, I'm wondering what I'm doing using EF in a performance area anyway. I'm still interested in the answer overall though: multiple select calls vs a single multi-resultset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> and I know database connections are usually one of the more expensive operations

Unless you turn off connection pooling, then as long as there are connections already established in the pool and available to use, obtaining a connection is pretty cheap. It also really shouldn't matter here anyway.

When it comes to two queries (whether EF or not) vs one query with two result sets (and using `NextResult` on the data reader) then you will gain a little, but really not much. Since there's no need to re-establish a connection either way, there's only a very small reduction in the overhead of one over the other, that will be dwarfed by the amount of actual data if the results are large enough for you to care much about this impact. (Less overhead again if you could union the two resultsets, but then you could do that with EF too anyway).

If you mean the bytes going too and fro over the connection *after* it's been established, then you should be able to send slightly less to the database (but we're talking a handful of bytes) and about the same coming back, assuming that your query is only obtaining what is actually needed. That is you do something like `from t in Table1Repository select new {t.ID, t.Name}` if you need ids and names rather than pulling back complete entities for each row.

EntityFramework does a whole bunch of things, and doing anything costs, so taking on more of the work yourself should mean you can be tighter. However, as well as introducing new scope for error over the tried and tested, you also introduce new scope for doing things less efficiently than EF does.

Any seeking of commonality between different pieces of database-handling code gets you further and further along the sort of path that ends up with you producing your own version of EntityFramework, but with the efficiency of all of it being up to you. Any attempt to streamline a particular query brings you in the opposite direction of having masses of similar, but not identical, code with slightly different bugs and performance hits.

In all, you are likely better off taking the EF approach first, and if a particular query proves particularly troublesome when it comes to performance then first see if you can improve it while remaining with EF (optimise the linq, use `AsNoTracking` when appropriate and so on) and if it is still a hotspot then try to hand-roll with ADO for just that part and measure. Until then, saying "yes, it would be slightly faster to use two resultsets with ADO.NET" isn't terribly useful, because just what that "slightly" is depends.

Comment: thanks for a great answer. What about the fact that multiple calls mean that (synchronously) the thread has to stop and wait on individual calls. In aggregate it just seems weird to wait for SQL Server 2 times instead of 1. I'm not trying to split hairs here or be wonkish; I just really am trying to strip down the time like I never have before.

Comment: That's not really here nor there, since the comparison is between 2 calls and 1 call that's twice as long. Indeed, it's the 2-call approach that has the potential to be turned into two simultaneous calls that are hence more performant. Such an approach might not really be more performant (threading overhead has an impact, bandwidth between application and DB might be a bottleneck that wouldn't get any better, multiple client calls to the same part of the application might mean it's already maxing out on CPU use, etc.) but the potential is certainly there to make use of the 2-call approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the query is a simple one to read from table1 and table2 then LinQ queries should give similar performance as executing stored procedure (plain SQL). But if the query runs across different databases then plain SQL is always better, where you can Union the result sets and have the data from all databases.
In MySQL "Explain" statement can be used to know the performance of query. See this link:
http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/
Another useful tool, is to check the SQL generated for your LinQ query in the output window of Microsoft Visual Studio. You can execute this query directly in a SQL editor and check the performance.